# How to sort a list in python

Tags: python, list, class, sorting, object

I'm creating a game in python and I need to get the first player to move round the table after each turn;

I've created a player object which contains a name that remains constant and an order which changes after each turn.

However I can't order by players so that the first player changes each time;

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.order = 0
        self.name = 0


player_count = 10
players = []

for i in range(player_count):
    players.append(i)
    players[i] = Player()
    players[i].name = i
    players[i].order = i

#def play_turn():
    #pass

for i in range(player_count):
    if i + 1 == player_count:
        players[i].order = 0
    else:
        players[i].order += 1
players.order.sort()

#play_turn()
```

It is saying:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order'

Comment: you want to sort according to `order` right?

Comment: so `players.sort(key = lambda x:x.order)` should do it